SwiftUI - ScrollView scroll to specific ID with offset
I have ScrollView which is utilizing the ScrollReader to scroll to a view with a specific ID:
withAnimation(.linear(duration: animationDuration)) {
    scrollViewReader.scrollTo(
        tab.id,
       anchor: .top
    )
}

Everything seems to work as expected but the issue here is that I want to scroll to .top + 50 offset.
The reason is that I have this big ScrollView with a sticky bar (tabs) with sections for each tab. The ScrollView goes under the sticky bar for a specific blur effect so when scrolling to .top, the top of the view is hidden under the bar. That's why I need the offset.
One solution would create a placeholder view and add them between the sections so I can scroll there but this seems to be a workaround and before exploring this kind of solution I wonder if there is a better way since I can't believe that ScrollViewReader doesn't have this functionality.

Instead of adding a placeholder view in-between the sections, you could add it in the background behind a section. Something like:
.background(alignment: .top) {
    VStack {
        Divider()
            .id(index)
    }
    .padding(.top, 50)
    .hidden()
}

Alternatively, if you were to show the tab area as an overlay over the top of the ScrollView then you can apply a corresponding y-offset to the sections inside the ScrollView. You then just need to add a dummy filler block below the last section, to compensate for the offset.
Here is an example to show it working:
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .indigo, .purple]
    let tabAreaHeight: CGFloat = 50

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewReader in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(Array(colors.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, color in
                        color
                            .frame(height: 250)
                            .id(index)
                            .offset(y: tabAreaHeight)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                                    scrollViewReader.scrollTo(
                                        index,
                                        anchor: .top
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.background)
                        .frame(height: tabAreaHeight)
                        .offset(y: tabAreaHeight)
                }
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Text("TAB AREA")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .frame(height: tabAreaHeight)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
            }
        }
    }
}

[
If this isn't suitable for your purposes then perhaps you can provide a more elaborate (working) example to illustrate your particular problem in more detail?
